# how to determine the row with button pressed?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, nsindexpath

I have my custom uitableviewcell. It has the uibutton, uibutton with action. So how do I know indexPath of the row with pressed uibutton??

Target: uibuttons on each rows has an image. So when user taps the button it shows the alertview and if answer is "yes" uibutton's image changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code snippet:

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method. set indexpath.row as button tag

> [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellBottonClicked:) 
>   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
>     cellButton.tag = indexPath.row;

```
-(IBAction) cellBottonClicked:(id)sender{
    NSInteger row = [sender tag];
    //you can get indexpath from row
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]; 
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[self.tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // from this cell you can fetch and change image of selected cell's button. 
}
```

**[EDIT : Change Only image of Button]**

If you only required to change Image of Button on click event.then I think, you do not need for indexpath or cell.

try this code. Hope it will helps:

```
-(IBAction) cellBottonClicked:(id)sender{
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
   [btn setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Comment: ok, NSLog(cell) gives me Null. So I have empty cell. Maybe I'm stupid but I don't understand for what we creates new cell and changing image of the NEW cell not existing??

Comment: here, "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method will return reference cell at selected indexpath and we are just referencing the same in "cell" variable. It'll not create new cell.

please, check for existence of self.tableView  and CustomTableViewCell. if not found, create reference variable with name "tableView" and connect the same with UI. for "CustomTableViewCell" replace it, with your created custom cell object.or use "UITableViewCell" object.

Comment: If you are using Group tableView. then you also need to check for proper Section number.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to get the indexPath by:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathForButton = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

**or** in your .h file, add:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* indexPathForButton;
```

and change the indexPath, whenever it's used. (self.indexPathForButton = indexPath;)

But using tags is much comfortable…

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the row of the current cell as the tag of the UIButton. On your target/action, you can check for the tag of the button to find the row in which it was pressed.

Comment: write the sample code, please. I'm not quite understand what do u mean.

Comment: Check the UIView documentation. There is a property called "tag" on UIView instance and its subclasses. On your – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can assign the indexPath.row value to the tag property of the UIButton instance.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: I know how to assign the indexPath.row to the UIButton.tag property. But I can't understand what to do next :\